# String.Format - what is wrong in my string?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I using `String.Format` this way:

```
String.Format("$(function() { $('{0}').menu(); });", "blaId");
```

I get an exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred and was caught.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should escape `{` characters like this: `{{`, unless they are a part of placeholders like `{0}`.

```
String.Format("$(function() {{ $('{0}').menu(); }});", "blaId");
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an invalid index value inside your curly braces. `String.Format` recognises this as a place holder for the formatting.

```
{ $('{0}').menu(); }
```

To resolve this, use double curly braces to escape:

```
String.Format("$(function() {{ $('{0}').menu(); }});", "blaId");
```

Comment: I believe it is not related to the fact that some curly braces are "inside" of other braces, as you said. I mean, a string like `"function() { return 1; } {0}"` would confuse `String.Format` just as well.

Answer (score 1):

escape `{` and `}`

```
  String.Format("$(function() {{ $('{0}').menu(); }});", "blaId");
```

Answer (score 1):

The other curly braces are confusing `String.Format`.

One solution is to write:

```
String.Format("$(function() {1} $('{0}').menu(); {2});", "blaId", "{", "}");
```

But it's better to escape the literals, like this:

```
String.Format("$(function() {{ $('{0}').menu(); }});", "blaId");
```

Comment: Yeah that first solution is horrible, I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: To be honest I've never had to escape the curly braces in a string.format before, so I wrote the first as a possibility, and then looked up the proper way of escaping them (during which time two other answers were written).  My first hunch was that they would be backslash escaped, but that turned out not to be the case.